# Azure CDN - Rewriting Url for Angular Application with Verizon in combination with Identity Server 4

Tags: angular, azure, identityserver4, azure-cdn, azure-storage-account

### Context

---

I am trying to setup my **Angular** project using **Azure CDN** in combination with **Verizon** to do the actual URL rewritting.

The **storage account** has been set up with a dedicated **blob container**.

[image]

and the **CDN-Profile** has been configured to make use of it.

[image]

What I would like to do is to redirect all incoming traffic so that **Angular** can work without any issues.

For that I use the [following](https://blog.lifeishao.com/2017/05/24/serving-your-static-sites-with-azure-blob-and-cdn/) two route engine rules:

[image]

This works quite well but the pattern doesn't support the redirect implementation of **Identity Server 4**.

### Problem

---

**Identity Server 4** is configured to redirect to the [following url](https://pastebin.com/5drAEyQE) (pastebin url) after a successful authentication.

After the redirect I currently get an `http 404` error.

I also get the same error if I just use the following url:

https://MyFancyWebsite.azureedge.net/security/callback

[image]

I don't mind creating the regex pattern by myself but to be honest I don't even know what the final URL should look like, so that **Angular** can work with it.

I would like to add that the current implementation works without any issues on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you need to modify your source pattern under Rules Engine to capture the `#`.

For the first source pattern, you could use `((?:[^\?]*/)?)($|[\?#].*)`, for the second source pattern, you could use `((?:[^\?]*/)?[^\?/.]+)($|[\?#].*)`. Here is the test for the second pattern:

[image]

Moreover, you could check the url with the regular expression under https://regex101.com and make sure the related blob exists. For example, `https://<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/cdn/security/callback/index.html`.